# Partial template specialization with inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

So, I have general template for vectors: `template<typename T>class Vector`,

a specialized version: `template<> class Vector<void*>`

and then a partial specialization: `template<typename T> class Vector<T*> : public Vector<void*>`

1. I have some issues with static cast, compiler gives me:

`invalid 'static_cast' from type 'void*' to type 'int*&'`  for `return static_cast<T*&>(BaseVec::operator[](i));`

```
void*& Vector<void*>::operator[] (int i) 
{
    if (i >= sz) 
        throw Range_Error(i);
    return arr[i];
}
```

And defined in class defintion of partial specialization is:

```
typedef Vector<void*> BaseVec;
T*& operator[] (int i) {
        if (i >= size()) 
            throw Range_Error(i);
        return static_cast<T*&>(BaseVec::operator[](i));
};
```

2. What is the syntax for defining function outside class for the partial specialization? I've tried `template<typename T>Vector<T*>::Vector()` for constructor and it gives me undefined reference.

Thanks for helping.

Edit: Added full code:

Header file:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector
{
    T *arr;
    int sz;
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(int sz);

    T& operator[] (int i);

    int size(); 
    void push_back(T elem);
    
    struct Range_Error;
};

template<> 
class Vector<void*>
{
    void **arr;
    int sz;
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(int sz);

    void*& operator[] (int i);

    int size();
    void push_back(void *elem);

    struct Range_Error;
};

template<typename T> 
class Vector<T*> : public Vector<void*> // idk syntax for defining functions outside, so they're all in here inline.
{
public:
    typedef Vector<void*> BaseVec;
    Vector() : BaseVec() {};
    explicit Vector(int sz) : BaseVec(sz) {}

    T*& operator[] (int i) {
        if (i >= size()) 
            throw Range_Error(i);
        return static_cast<T*&>(BaseVec::operator[](i));
    };
    struct Range_Error {
        int i;
        Range_Error(int i) : i(i) {}
    };
};
```

vector.cpp file

```
template<typename T>
struct Vector<T>::Range_Error
{
    int i;
    Range_Error(int i) : i(i) {}
};

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector() : sz(0), arr(nullptr) {}

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int sz) : sz(sz) 
{
    arr = (T) malloc(sz*sizeof(T));
}

template<typename T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[] (int i) 
{
    if (i >= sz) 
        throw Range_Error(i);
    return arr[i];
}

template<typename T>int Vector<T>::size() {return sz;}

template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::push_back(T elem)
{
    T* tmp;
    ++sz;
    
    tmp = realloc(arr, sizeof(T)*sz);
    if (tmp == nullptr)
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    arr = tmp;
    arr[sz-1] = elem;
}

// Specialized Vector Template

Vector<void*>::Vector() : sz(0), arr(nullptr) {}

Vector<void*>::Vector(int sz) : sz(sz) 
{
    arr = (void**) malloc(sz*sizeof(void*));
}

struct Vector<void*>::Range_Error
{
    int i;
    Range_Error(int i) : i(i) {}
};

void*& Vector<void*>::operator[] (int i) 
{
    if (i >= sz) 
        throw Range_Error(i);
    return arr[i];
}

int Vector<void*>::size() {return sz;}

void Vector<void*>::push_back(void* elem)
{
    void** tmp;
    ++sz;
    
    tmp = (void**) realloc(arr, sizeof(void*)*sz);
    if (tmp == nullptr)
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    arr = tmp;
    arr[sz-1] = elem;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    int *intarr = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        intarr[i] = i*i;

    Vector<int*>vci;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        vci.push_back(intarr+i);
    for (int i = 0; i < vci.size();i++)
        std::cout << vci[i] << ", ";
}
```

Comment: Try posting a minimally compilable example. I gave up trying to invent the missing code.

Comment: remove the reference from the cast. `return static_cast<T*>(BaseVec::operator[](i));` it's enough

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper gives me error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int*&' to an rvalue of type 'int*

Comment: Oh well i didnt noticed that the other operator[] returns a reference, in this case you have to cast its pointer 'return *static_cast<T**>(&BaseVec::operator[](i));' would work. Sorry i m from smartphone so i cant test

Comment: Yes @IkarusDeveloper, that does work.

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper yes, it works now, thank you!

Comment: does anyone know syntax for defining partial specialization class members outside?